# Is any suitable gem for surveys in rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, survey

I want to create an application where customers create their own surveys and where users can take the surveys. Are there any survey gem available for the above requirements? I used surveyor, which supports static surveys, but I want dynamic surveys, where customers can create their own surveys as they wish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find what you were looking for? I also need the user to create their own surveys. Thanks

Comment: It would take you a few hours, at most, to build your own survey module. While I don't often advise you reinvent the wheel, you will save yourself a lot of headaches down the road when you decide to customise the format.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [Surveyor](https://github.com/NUBIC/surveyor). Its pretty uptodate, running on Rails 3, hosted on Github (with many forks) and has a beautiful DSL to define survey forms.

Comment: beautiful!! after wrestling with SMERF for about half an hour, surveyor took me 1 minute to install.

Comment: surveyor hasn't been maintained in 9 years.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147801/is-there-an-open-source-ruby-on-rails-online-questionnaire-template). Short summary, they recommand: [SMERF](https://github.com/springbok/smerf).

I also found this [one called Survey Builder](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=12).

Comment: The question you point to was removed from SO

Comment: SMERF hasn't been maintained in 12 years.